# Passing a global reference to beego controllers

Tags: go, beego

I'm trying to pass a logger reference initialised inside main.go to Controller layer via the router like bellow

main.go

```
logger, _ := zap.NewProduction()
defer logger.Sync() // flushes buffer, if any
sugar := logger.Sugar()
routers.Init(sugar)
```

routers.go

```
func Init(l *zap.SugaredLogger) {
   nsMgt := beego.NewNamespace("/api",
    beego.NSNamespace("/account",
        beego.NSInclude(
            &controllers.AccountController{
                Logger: l,
            },
        ),
    ),
   )
)
```

controller.go

```
type AccountController struct {
   beego.Controller
   Logger *zap.SugaredLogger
}

// @Title Get account details.
// @Summary Get account details
// @Param   filterKey query string  true "possible values 'id' or 'username'"
// @Param   filterValue query string  true "value of the filter key"
// @Success 200 {object} models.User
// @router / [get]
func (o *AccountController) Get() {
     o.Logger.Info("this is cool")
}
```

It throws a null pointer error at the controller function. Is there a way to pass a global logger variable to controller layer?. It's important to initialise the logger at the main function 'cause it requires a defered close.

Comment: Instead of having an init() function, you should really do that in the main function. If you want to reduce the amount of stuff in main, make a function like NewController(Logger) that returns the controller, so that you can initialize the router in the main function--just a general idea for structure.

Comment: Are you checking for errors when creating the logger? Go best practices for error returns are to return a nil pointer to the expected value and an error (i.e. return nil, err), so if it's failing to create the logger you would encounter this problem.

Comment: @AniSkywalker Ofcourse I checked errors. just put the whole thing in the simplest possible way. Question is simple why o.Logger is nil?

Comment: I can't see why this is happening from the provided code. Could you make a minimal playground example?

Answer (score 1):

Beego uses reflection to create a controller instance for each request, it doesn't use the actual instance you pass in and it doesn't passes the params to the new instances. You can define "Prepare" method on your controller which will be called by Beego in runtime before invoking the matched controller method, there you can initialize the required struct fields (e.g. service layer) by calling a factory method or some sort of IoC container (Not sure if this is the best practice for Go)

I also looked for an option to pass dependencies when initializing the struct but it's not possible at the moment.

Take a look on the request handling logic: https://beego.me/docs/mvc/

Prepare method is documented here:
https://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/controller.md

Comment: I'm aware of the prepare method. Idea here is to use a single logger instance across all the controllers and the prepare method doesn't allow that. I do not think Go encourage factories or any design patterns which defeat the simplicity of the design.

Comment: Go encourages working with interfaces, factory method allows you to do so very easily, I don't see any bad practice here. Additionally, until you will have solution to passing params in controller instance you need a way to populate the struct dependency, working with some sort of IoC container or factory to create the instances seems like a good solution, it can use the same Logger instance, it all depends on your implementation.

Comment: Is this allowed now?

Comment: @ABAA in latest Beego versions you can pass dependencies when creating controller instance.